# Averaging runtimes for performance analysis

Tags: runtime, perf, performance-measuring

So modern computers and OSes are complicated, and there is a lot of stuff going on that makes accurate predictions and repeatability of runtimes difficult, like schedulers, branch predictors, caches, prefetchers, etc. I don't understand these things, but I thought I understood the implication: running it once isn't enough.

Luckily, `perf stat` provides a `--repeat` command, and even gives you rudimentary statistics. So to test this, I ran

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    puts("Hello, World!");
    return 0;
}
```

compiled with `gcc -O2 hello.c -o hello` with the command `perf stat -r 100 ./hello`. This gives me nice output like this

```
    0,00043149 +- 0,00000688 seconds time elapsed  ( +-  1,59% )
```

However, if I now run this whole thing again a couple of times, the average runtime can be far away from the previous run:

```
    0,00043149 +- 0,00000688 seconds time elapsed  ( +-  1,59% )
    0,00043222 +- 0,00000657 seconds time elapsed  ( +-  1,52% )
    0,00041690 +- 0,00000612 seconds time elapsed  ( +-  1,47% )
    0,00045048 +- 0,00000832 seconds time elapsed  ( +-  1,85% )
    0,0005051  +- 0,0000232 seconds time elapsed  ( +-  4,60% )
    0,00043595 +- 0,00000676 seconds time elapsed  ( +-  1,55% )
    0,0004271  +- 0,0000168 seconds time elapsed  ( +-  3,94% )
    0,00043166 +- 0,00000604 seconds time elapsed  ( +-  1,40% )
    0,0010521 +- 0,0000548 seconds time elapsed  ( +-  5,21% )
    0,00042799 +- 0,00000714 seconds time elapsed  ( +-  1,67% )
```

Here the relative deviation of the averages is 37%, largely caused by the 2nd to last outlier. But even if I discount that run, its still 5.5%, much larger than the deviations from a "single" run.

So what is happening here? Why doesn't averaging work (in this case)? What should I be doing?

**Edit:** This also happens when the frequency scaling is disabled (`sudo cpupower frequency-set --governor performance`), but the outliers seem less frequent.

Comment: The execution time is less than a millisecond and dynamic factors can cause a relatively significant variation in this specific scenario. This is normal on a typical system. Change the program to do a little more work so that execution time is at the order of several milliseconds at least.

Comment: This is not a real world example, and if that means this approach is not correct for performance analysis of this, fair enough. But that doesn't explain what is going on here. For one, the execution time of the averaging run is around 150ms, so why isn't that enough? If dynamic factors can cause significant variation, why don't they do that within an averaging run (most times only 1.5%)?

Comment: What 150ms? The perf output shows about 0.4ms.

Comment: Running `./hello` once takes 0.4ms, running it 100 times with `perf` takes about 150ms.

Comment: Huh? That's irrelevant. What matters is the time of a single run and the variation of across multiple runs. Also, how did you measure 150ms? It should be about 0.4*100 = 40ms.

Comment: By running `perf stat perf stat -r 100 ./hello`, which gives `0.163721200 seconds time elapsed`. So I guess the difference (~120ms) is the overhead of perf and starting 100 processes?